# Recursively compute difference between consecutive records within each group

Tags: r, group-by, difference

Goodmorning StackOverflow,

I have seen answer to similar question, however, they do not consider the `group_ID` and are not efficient enough to be run on massive datasets.

I am struggling to find a solution to the following task:
**within** the consecutive elements of each `group_ID`, recursively compute the `difference` with the **previous** element starting **from the second** to the last element belonging to that group_ID.

Therefore, considering the following sample data:

```
data <- data.frame(time = c(1:3, 1:4),
                   group_ID = c(rep(c("1", "2"), c(3, 4))),
                   value = c(0, 400, 2000, 0, 500, 2000, 2120))
```

The expected result of the solution I am trying to find is:

```
solution_df <- data.frame(time = c(1:3, 1:4),
                          group_ID = c(rep(c("1", "2"), c(3, 4))),
                          difference = c(NA, 400, 1600, NA, 500, 1500, 120))
```

It is critical to bear in mind the dataset is massive and the solution must be efficient.

I hope the question was clear, otherwise please ask for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data.table for grouping and `diff` to calculate the differences.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, .(time = time,
  difference = c(NA, diff(value))), by = group_ID]

#   group_ID time difference
#1:        1    1         NA
#2:        1    2        400
#3:        1    3       1600
#4:        2    1         NA
#5:        2    2        500
#6:        2    3       1500
#7:        2    4        120
```

I don't know what is supposed to be recursive here.

Comment: Thank you. With recursive I meant for each group. What was the correct term?

Comment: following your data.table solution, can I change `difference()` with `distGeo()` which take the latitude and logitude between two adjacent records and return the difference in terms of distance?

Comment: Probably. But your speed bottleneck might be that function (which I don't know) then. Have you done some profiling?

Comment: Apparently it is not possible to apply `distGeo` instead of `diff()` because the first takes two argument whereas `diff()` compute the difference between records by itself.

Comment: If you have a different question please ask a different question. I believe my answer fully addresses your question as asked.

Comment: You definetly did. I was just trying to understand whether this same solution could be used to solve also another question :)